# How can this be an 'unclear' post?

Tags: discussion

I really don't understand how this post can be closed as 'unclear what you are asking'. I look at the details of the posting as well as the answers already provided and short of the poster answering his own question, I don't see how it could be any clearer. What am I missing?

[Steady RF noise from S7 to 20 over](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/steady-rf-noise-from-s7-to-20-over)

Answer (score 1):

I closed this as “unclear what you’re asking” for the reason stated in my comment. It is not a question, it is a statement of a set of facts, literally followed by “... any ideas?”

A good question will be answerable. I could easily have closed it as “too broad” or “opinion based”, as it is difficult for anyone to do anything more than make suggestions.

Any ideas? Yes - please rephrase the whole question in the form of an actual question that has a definitive answer.

Even if the OP had rewritten the last paragraph to ask if these symptoms are something that people come across often or not, I would have left it open. I closed it because after the suggestion that the question be rewritten to make a good question out of it, some further edits were made that did not improve it.

Comment: Somebody else could edit it so that it could be reopened. :-)

Comment: @MikeWaters I don't agree but I have done as you suggested. Please revisit the question.

Comment: Ok Glenn. I'll reopen it and hopefully make some more useful changes.

Comment: Edited and reopened. Any suggestions and/or edits are welcome! :-)

Comment: Thinking this over, I actually like the original question title better than what I changed it to. There is no SE guideline anywhere that implies that the title has to end with a question mark.  **Having said that**, *S9 to 20 over* conflicts with his statement that the noise level never varies. I'm guessing that he is saying that the noise level varies only when he switches bands.